# Subset data table by all unique entries in columns whose name contain a certain substring, fill with NA for other entries

Tags: r, datatable, subset, unique

I have a data table and I'd like to copy or subset to all the unique observations in variables whose variable name contains a certain substring. I can conceive of a way to do it clunkily with for loops, but that seems to defeat the utility and speed of a data table.

For example:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dt <- setDT(tibble(a_ID = c(1, 1, 2, 11, 2),
                   b = c('x','y','z','z', 'x'),
                   b_ID = c('XY','XY','XY','XY', 'XY'),
                   d = 1:5))
```

What I would like to do from here is subset by all columns whose name contains 'ID', returning only the unique entries from each column, and since that will result in columns with differing amounts of observations for each, fill with `NA` for the rest.

That is, I'd like to return the following:

```
subset_dt <- setDT(tibble(a_ID = c(1,2,11),
                          b_ID = c('XY', NA,NA)))
```

Is this possible with data.table functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may get the `unique` elements and then `replace` the `duplicated` with `NA`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, lapply(.SD, unique), .SDcols = patterns("_ID$")][,
    lapply(.SD, \(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))]
```

-output

```
    a_ID   b_ID
   <num> <char>
1:     1     XY
2:     2   <NA>
3:    11   <NA>
```

---

Or another option with `unique`

```
unique(dt[, .(a_ID, b_ID)])[, lapply(.SD, \(x) fcase(!duplicated(x), x))]
    a_ID   b_ID
   <num> <char>
1:     1     XY
2:     2   <NA>
3:    11   <NA>
```

---

Or another option is to block the code, check for the `length`s after the `unique` step and append `NA` to fix the length

```
dt[, {lst1 <- lapply(.SD, unique)
     mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
    lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx)}, .SDcols = patterns("_ID$")]
    a_ID   b_ID
   <num> <char>
1:     1     XY
2:     2   <NA>
3:    11   <NA>
```

---

We may also use `collapse` - select the columns (`gvr`), get the unique rows (`funique`), loop over the columns with `dapply`, `replace` the duplicates with `NA`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(funique(gvr(dt, "_ID$")), MARGIN = 2, 
   FUN = \(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA))
    a_ID   b_ID
   <num> <char>
1:     1     XY
2:     2   <NA>
3:    11   <NA>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Can you explain what the second `lapply` function is? I'm not sure I understand the `\(x) replace(x,duplicated(x), NA))` is referencing. Is the `\(x)` the returned list of entries for each column?